# Loading TinyMCE without Cloud in React

Tags: reactjs, npm, tinymce

I am working on React project that uses TinyMCE as a rich-text editor. I wanted to opt out of their cloud services so as to remove the following message.

> This domain is not registered with TinyMCE Cloud. Start a free trial to discover our premium cloud services and pro support.

I tried out [this link (Loading TinyMCE by yourself)](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/react/#loadingtinymcebyyourself) from the TinyMCE website by adding the following code to my `index.html` file hoping that it would be accessible globally.

```
<script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/5/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

This did not work nevertheless. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

The URL in your script tag is using our Cloud service to try to load the editor so if you don't want to use our Cloud platform, then that URL seems not to be what you want.

> If you want to locally host TinyMCE in a React app. You can do so via a module loader as outlined here:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/usage-with-module-loaders/

> If you want to use the script tag referenced in your question you need to register on our Cloud platform (it's free) to get an API key.  Once you have that, you need to include that API key in your script tag as outlined here:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/cloud-deployment-guide/editor-and-features/

...so the script tag would look like this:

```
<script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/5/tinymce.min.js?apiKey=your_API_key"></script>
```

...but with the string `your_API_key` replaced with your actual API key.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I just had to download the `tinymce.min.js` file and add that to my `assets` folder and add a script tag to my `index.html`. They key thing to note from the instructions [here](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/react/#loadingtinymcebyyourself) is that the `js` file needs to be hosted by us. Using the public script won't work. So the script looked like this for me.

```<script src="assets/tinymce.min.js"></script>```

Answer (score 1):

I'v got a new way to get rid of the cloud when using official tinymce react package.

1. Go to https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-react, and clone the whole project.
2. Open the file src/main/ts/components/Editor.tsx, and go to line 122, where you can find the function named 'getScriptSrc'.
3. Remove all codes inside the function, and just return the url of your self hosted tinymce.min.js. In this way you can get official tinymce react but won't get bothered by the message.
4. Import Editor in src/main/ts/index.ts.